# Why can the Yearling badge be awarded multiple times?

Tags: discussion, badges, yearling-badge

Is the [Yearling badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/13/yearling) meant to be awarded every year to active users?

This behavior seems...odd.  Certainly if we take "yearling" literally.

Comment: You mean if they post one bad answer they should be shot behind a curtain out on the course where the railbirds are eating their stubs?

Comment: I'm sure it didn't use to say "This badge can be awarded multiple times.". Must be a recent change, perhaps it's to encourage people to stick around.

Comment: It's just a worthless silver.  1/year is not a big deal in my opinion. Why not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should the "yearling" badge recur?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62481/should-the-yearling-badge-recur)

Comment: @Popular, a duplicate of a question asked months after mine?  My DeLorean is in the shop.

Comment: @JXG, yeah, it's unusual, but that one has a moderator red tag and a Jeff Atwood answer, so I figured it was a special case. I don't care enough about it to follow up at this point, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like it. Maybe when you get 10 it'll convert into the Decader badge.

Comment: Make that gold please

Comment: "Decadeling"? "Yeartenling"?

Comment: "Decader" is a reference to the book Anathem by Neal Stephenson.