# Should the "yearling" badge recur?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, yearling-badge

I just got my yearling badge... for the second time.  That seems a little odd to me.  If we want a badge on every anniversary, that's fine, but the yearling name to me indicates a one-time operation.

Comment: Can we remove the [status-bydesign] and [bug] tags and move this to [discussion]?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can the Yearling badge be awarded multiple times?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38249/why-can-the-yearling-badge-be-awarded-multiple-times)

Answer (score 17):

I just got my second Yearling badge and I was just as astonished as the OP.  I would suggest a rewording from:

> Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

to:

> Active member for at least a year, earning at least 200 reputation. This badge is awarded multiple times, one per year of membership.

However, **even better would be to introduce a new badge**, and move "Yearling" back to being a one-time only badge. For two years, award a silver "Toddler" badge, another uniquely-named one for three years, and so on.  The overall badge count would not change, but then the user won't have two of the same badge, and moreover the ordering of the "Yearling" badge award will not be shifted. (I enjoy seeing the order in which I received my badges - e.g. receiving "Fanatic" before "Yearling" and after "Great Answer" etc. Duplicate badges screws up the order.)

Answer (score 11):

Per the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/13/yearling):

> Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation. **This badge can be awarded multiple times.**

Yes, it should recur, since we always designed it to recur from day one.

Comment: Then the name should be changed, since a yearling means a one year old - http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yearling?show=0&t=1282888950

Comment: @Peter: Err... vote to close as "belongs on English Language and Usage" ? ;) See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2049/is-the-word-yearling-appropriate-for-a-recurring-event

Comment: I see that now on the page for the badge, but it's not in the description shown on the stackoverflow.com/badges page.

Comment: the results are in, and you can go on and use "yearling", but that was a close one ;) This [answer summarizes it nicely](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2049/is-the-word-yearling-appropriate-for-a-recurring-event/2061#2061).

Comment: Is it unfair to say that even if it's by design, it's really stupid? There are also problems with the bronze/silver tag badges -- I received a bronze one for the same tag I'd already gotten silver, and had never gotten bronze before I got the silver.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can get it more than once, that being said...

I think it's only special the first time. So should only happen once.

Maybe a 5 (then 10) year anniversary badge at some point would be nice.

In [the real world](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=define%3Ayearling&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) a yearling is between 1 and 2 years old.

Answer (score 0):

And then, whatever happened? It's been quite sometime and the *Yearlings* keep growing older! I am looking towards the coming 10 months+ by which time, well, I should hopefully deserve to be a "yearling" myself. And then what? A *multiyearling*, maybe?